# ClassNotFoundException for MySQL driver JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jboss

I've been struggling to get a MySQL connection working in my application for a few days now. I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException on com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. There's been a lot of threads on this but nothing has solved my problem and I'm a bit lost now.

Everything was working a few days ago, but then I restructured the code into several modules and deployed them in an ear file. Since then I have not been able to access the database at all.

I have a MySQL driver and datasource set up in JBoss which after a lot of messing around finally seems to be working. I can check in the admin console and test the connection and all seems well.

But I still get the ClassNotFoundException at runtime...

```
20:09:25,854 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.traintrack-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]

20:09:25,858 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

20:09:25,858 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)

20:09:25,862 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)

20:09:25,866 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)

20:09:25,866 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)

20:09:25,870 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

20:09:25,870 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
```

Here is the relevant part of my standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/MySqlDSJNDI" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trainingTracker</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jarcom.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

The driver is deployed as a module in $JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\mysql\main. Here's the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">  
   <resources>  
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar"/>  

   </resources>   

   <dependencies>  
      <module name="javax.api"/>  
    </dependencies>  
</module>
```

This appears to be ok since it's registered in the admin panel and the connection tests are successful but maybe a keener eye can find an issue.

I'm building this with Maven and the dependency is in my pom.xml as provided scope.

Any help on this would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would love to help you, but short of a consulting some tea leaves, I don't think this is a problem that we can remotely diagnose and fix

Comment: What's the missing class ?

Comment: Of course, but I'm not asking for a solution, just some pointers to get me started. I've run out of ideas

Comment: Sorry, it's com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Question updated

Comment: Well, consider update your question with the module for mysql driver on JBoss, the stack trace of your error and the datasource config. Maybe we can help you.

Comment: have you added the mysql jar and module.xml into jboss/modules folder?

Comment: Question updated with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I had to put a dependency on the SQL driver in the manifest of my ear. Thanks for the help